# How do I run code before hoisted require statements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require, hoisting

I want to generate a file at the beginning of my program. This must happen before the module is loaded, as the module will try to load that file.

Here is my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');

    //if cert doesn't exist, create the file from an environment variable
    if (!fs.existsSync('./ca-certificate.crt')) {
        if (!process.env.MONGO_CERT) throw new Error('The mongo cert wasnt found as a file or in environment variables');

        fs.writeFileSync('./ca-certificate.crt',process.env.MONGO_CERT);
        console.log('wrote MONGO_CERT to file');
    } else console.log('Mongo cert file detected');

const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const busboy = require('express-busboy');
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const queue = require('./queue.js');
```

and queue.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const {MongoClient, Collection} = require('mongodb');
const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGO_URI);
```

The problem is the app crashes in `module.js` due to not being able to find the file. I believe this to be due to node hoisting the `module` definition to before my if statement, so that whole module is getting run before even getting to my code.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: No, `require` calls are not hoisted.

Comment: Can you share your entire code please, including the contents of *module.js* and how you are calling that script?

Comment: added more complete code (the top of each file)

Comment: Is `queue.js` actually `module.js`?

Comment: Can you include the error?  I don't see what code in queue.js would trigger any usage of `ca-certificate.crt`...